# NSTableView Horizontal Scroll Cuts off last column

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I created a brand new Swift Cocoa Macos project, and placed a `NSTableView`. I auto layouted it, and then ran the app, and got this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQmQD.png

If I shrink the window down just a **tiny** bit more, then the horizontal scroll bar will appear.

Steps to reproduce using XCode 12:

1. Create a new Macos App using storyboards
2. Add a NSTableView, and in interface builder place it on the top left corner. Proceed to make it the same size of the window.
3. Add 4 constraints on all sides of the NSTableView so that it is the same size as your window, even if you resize the window.
4. Add 3 more columns and name your columns whatever you want.
5. Proceed to run the app, shrink the right border of the window, and you can see, you can shrink your window past the point of last column, so it's possible that the last column is obstructed and the H-Scrollbar is still not visible. It only shows when you shrink the window even more.

**Desired Behavior:**
As soon as I resize the window so it can now no longer fit all the columns, the horizontal scroll bar appears.

Is there anyway to solve this, like a hidden setting?
I've tried reproducing this 4 times, and I was successful.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: The desired behavior is that as soon as I resize the window so that it can no longer fit all the columns, the H-Scroll bar appears

Comment: Have you tried the "Column Sizing" setting of the table view and the "Resizing" setting and the width contraints of the columns?

Comment: @Willeke Yes! Setting column sizing seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to set Column Sizing of your table view to your desired settings.